# How to enable deleting non-contenteditable div inside contenteditable div

Tags: html, cross-browser, contenteditable

I was trying to have a non-editable but deletable div inside a contenteditable div (All this is happening inside a WYSIWYG editor, Quill).

I tried setting the child div contenteditable="false" and that made it non-editable but it also made it non-deletable in Google Chrome when it's not surrounded by editable content (Works on Edge, funnily enough). Forcefully adding some content before & after the child div is not an option as it would unnecessarily add an extra line

```html
<div contenteditable="true">
  <p><strong>Editable</strong> Text</p>
  <div contenteditable="false">Non Editable Text</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made a following observation after brief testing in chrome, we are not able to delete the non-editable div if it is forming a Block Formatting Context [BFC] ([reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context)), you will be able to delete the div if your non-editable div is not a BFC.

Here's a simple example which doesn't make the div a BFC.

```html
<style>
  [contenteditable=false] {
    display: inline-block;
  }
</style>
<div contenteditable="true">
  <p><strong>Editable</strong> Text</p>
  <div contenteditable="false">Non Editable Text</div>
</div>
```

> **PS:** As I mentioned, this solution is based on observation and it works, but I am not sure about why it behaves like this, hopefully someone can explain the **WHY** of this

Comment: thank you, I tried to solve a combination of contenteditable and custom element, trying to delete it or place cursor before/after it. This combination (inline-block+contenteditable:false) led me to expected result :D